# bootstrap nav affix w/ animation (slidedown/slideup)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, nav, affix

Looking to create a navigation that behaves like the nav on http://www.invisionapp.com/

The following code causes my nav to slide down after crossing the `data-offset-top` position (while scrolling down the page), but I can't figure out how to slide the nav back up when crossing the `data-offset-top` position (while scrolling up the page).

```
$('#navigation').on('affixed.bs.affix',function(){
    $(this).height('75');
    $(this).slideDown(200);
});
```

Does anybody have a working fiddle for a nav that works like http://www.invisionapp.com/? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe late, but still I've got an answer for you :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to achieve the same thing as you need with Bootstrap 3 affix but without success. So, instead of playing with the Bootstrap affix, it was easier to create a custom sticky navigation.

In my scenario, the navigation that was supposed to become sticky after reaching certain pixel offset by scrolling. Before reaching the point, the navigation is hidden. When it shows, it slides from the top. When I scroll back, it slides to the top away from the screen.

**HTML part**

Add any content into the div, I have a logo and the main navigation in there.

```
<div id="menu-bar"></div>
```

**CSS part**

I use CSS3 transitions as they are [well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions) (except IE <= 9) and their animation suits the desired effect the most, way better than jQuery animate(). jQuery animate() effect is slowed down when I continue scrolling after reaching the offset to start the animation. With CSS3, there is no need to stop scrolling to have the animation fluent and its effect is still immediate.

```
#menu-bar {
    position: fixed;
    top: -200px;
    width: 100%;
    transition: top 0.5s ease 0s;
    -webkit-transition: top 0.5s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: top 0.5s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: top 0.5s ease 0s;
}
```

**JavaScript part**

I use jQuery, maybe you could do without it, but it would be much more complicated than this solution. You use jQuery for Bootstrap anyway.

```
var $document = $(document),
    $element = $('#menu-bar');

$document.scroll(function() {
    if ($document.scrollTop() >= 850) {
        $element.stop().css({
            top: '0px'
        });
    } else {
        $element.stop().css({
            top: '-200px'
        });
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yu788m36/) to see it in action! I added a few styles so the sticky element can be easily seen.